# Testing Performance or load in WPF application using VS2013

Tags: wpf, performance, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

I have a WPF application using standard MVVM pattern. I want to test its performance and load . I see in Visual studio 2013 there is an option to check for Web Performance and Load test . I tried the Load test part of it, but Load test accepts only a test type i.e Unit Test or Coded UI test.

My question is : Cant i directly test the Load of my application without any test cases. Or what is the correct process to test my WPF application.

Comment: Visual Studio's "Load Tests" are used to run test cases many times to simulate a number of users repeatedly executing those tests. You may find that Visual Studio's profiling tools are more useful in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Never run load test on WPF or any kind of UI application. Load testing is generally done on the tier supporting the load : asp.net, Web Api, WCF ...and sometimes DB.

On UI-tier, it's better to do performance test, I mean simulating a huge amount of data coming from data-tier or with a high rate of transactions/sec. [Visual Studio Profiler & Profiling tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx) will help you to determine the Hot Path and to find application bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks Max. Regarding the load test can i do it on WCF service which my WPF application calls to get the data . Any useful tips or suggestions for the same.

Comment: Use integration tests (with unit tests) and add them into the load test. The most painful part is parameterization, such as simulating login from random users